# Filter data by different time intervals

Tags: postgresql

I need to filter my query with different time intervals like that:

```
...
where
date >= '2011-07-01' and date <='2011-09-30'
and date >='2012-07-01' and date >='2012-09-30'
```

I suppose such code is not good, because these dates conflicts with each other. But how to filter only these two intervals, skipping everything else? Is it even possible? Because if I query like this, I don't get any results.I tried to use BETWEEN, but it does same thing.

I bypassed this by extracting quarters from years and calculating only third quarter. But then other quarters sum is showed as zero and I can't ignore these rows that have sum column with zero value. I tried to filter where `price > 0` (column where sum goes), but it says that column do not exist. So I put it whole `FROM` under '('')' brackets to make it calculate sum before where clause, but it still does give me error that such column do not exist.

Also if you need to see query I have now, I can post it, just tell me if it is needed.

I want to do this, because I need to compare third quarter of two different years (maybe I should use another approach).

Comment: Try replacing the middle `AND` with `OR`, then show query if problem not solved.

Comment: Thanks! How could I not thought about that:). That what happens when you start to think too complex and miss simple things:)

@TerjeD. Can I mark comment as answer? Because I don't see an option there.

Comment: No, you need an answer in order to accept.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get any results because you can't have a date that's both within 7/1/2011 through 9/30/11 and after 7/1/2012 and after 9/30/12.

You can have a date that is **either** between 7/1/20122 and 9/30/2011 **or** between 7/1/2012 and 9/30/2012.

```
SELECT col1 FROM table1
WHERE date BETWEEN '7/1/2011' AND '9/30/2011' OR date BETWEEN '7/1/2012' AND '9/30/2012';
```

Comment: Well actually I've actually got that date by using `or` instead of `and`. And I checked it by puting quarter column. So it showed at which quarter which row belonged. And it only showed third quarter which was in my where clause (also I can see that both years third quarters were taken, because my query calculated difference from sales of those quarters)